# When declaring a variable in javascript, is the default value null?

Tags: javascript

If I have a declaration as follows:

```
var j;
```

does `j==null` until I set it equal to something?

Comment: `j==null` will be `true`, but not because `j` is `null`. Instead it's because `j` is `undefined`, but the `==` operator does type coercion. The `==` considers `null` and `undefined` to be equal. The `===` operator is strict, and doesn't do any coercion.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No, it has the default value of `undefined`
But if want to use the `!j` condition, it will work with both the values (i.e. **undefined** or **null**)

Note that `(j==null)` is **`true`**, but `(j===null)` is **`false`**... JavaScript have "falsy" values and sometimes unexpected rules to convert values, plus fancy `===` operator to compare value and type at the same time.

Comment: Actually, j == null will evaluate to true, j === null will be false. (But yes, the default value is undefined as j === undefined will be true).

Comment: so will writing k === null evaluate to true, since variable k doesn't exist? also i assume i can use the opposite, and say "if(j)", and that will evaluate to false, correct?

Comment: @thisissami no, it'll throw a ReferenceError. The tricky thing to get is that *undefined* is actually a valid value. There are both `null` and `undefined`, they are similar but different.

Comment: @thisissami but yes, `j`will evaluate as `false` in a boolean context so `if (j) expr()` will not run `expr`.

Comment: @MarkLinus: No it doesn't. `j==null` will be `true` if `j` is `undefined`. See points 2 and 3 in [the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3).

Comment: comment was deleted, but I'm leaving the [ECMA reference on equality comparison.](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.3)

Comment: ok thanks for all the comments guys. my one question that's bugging me - when do things get set to null in javascript? only when they're manually set to that value?

Comment: They can be manually set or set by values returned from functions, like document.getElementById(elementThatDontExists);

Comment: javascript === cringe; // true