# Javascript unassigned var?

Tags: javascript

What happens to a variable declared in Javascript, if no initial value was assigned to it?

Let's suppose that I declare the variable as below

`var cancel;`

Now, does this variable "cancel" has a value or is it null or what?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript <- This would be a better duplicate question to link to.

Answer (score 4):

`undefined` is a property of the *global object*, i.e. it is a variable in global scope. The initial value of `undefined` is the primitive value `undefined`.

In modern browsers (JavaScript 1.8.5 / Firefox 4+), `undefined` is a **non-configurable, non-writable property** per the ECMAScript 5 specification. Even when this is not the case, avoid overriding it.

A variable that has not been assigned a value is of type `undefined`. A method or statement also returns `undefined` if the variable that is being evaluated does not have an assigned value. A function returns `undefined` if a value was not returned.

Since `undefined` is not a ***reserved* word**, it can be used as an identifier (variable name) in any scope other than the global scope.

### Example

```
var x;
if (x === undefined) {
    // these statements execute
}
else {
    // these statements do not execute
}
```

---

### typeof operator

Alternatively, `typeof` can be used:

```
var x;
if (typeof x === 'undefined') {
    // these statements execute
}
```

One reason to use `typeof` is that it does not throw an error if the variable has not been defined.

```
// x has not been defined before
if (typeof x === 'undefined') { // evaluates to true without errors
    // these statements execute
}

if(x === undefined){ // throws a ReferenceError

}
```

---

### void operator

The `void` operator is a third alternative.

```
var x;
if (x === void 0) {
    // these statements execute
}

// y has not been defined before
if (y === void 0) {
    // throws a ReferenceError (in contrast to `typeof`)
}
```

---

Source: [MDN - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

Answer (score 0):

If you just execute the following you will see the alert box with **undefined** value. Just try yourself in Firebug or chrome developer tool

```
var cancel;
alert(cancel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Undeclared variables or variables without a value have a type of 'undefined'.

It's important to note that unlike some other languages (like PHP, for example) 'undefined' is a Javascript keyword that can be checked against, for example:

```
if(cancel == undefined) { alert('Cancel is undefined!'); };
```

You can check for the type of a Javascript variable using the javascript

```
typeof
```

command, for example:

```
var cancel;
var typeOfCancel = typeof cancel; // In this case, undefined

var cancel = true;
var typeOfCancel = typeof cancel; // In this case, boolean
```

This can lead to an extra check, when working with javascript, to see if a variable has been set, as in:

```
if(cancel == undefined || cancel == null || cancel == '') {
    // React to the empty value here
}
```

You can see this working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/7bu84/

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote?

Comment: Reason is incorrect usage of `==` operator, which coerces `undefined`, `null` and empty string all to falsy, thus invalidating your checks for `undefined`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/10560362/1594449.