# Iterate and Enumerate Key Value Pairs of Multiple Arrays in an Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

My question is in regards to the following function:

```
function loadConfigurations(configs){
  console.log(configs);
}
```

The 'configs' object that the loadConfigurations function receives, contains two properties --two arrays one called "assigned" the other called "unassigned".  And executing console.log(configs) outputs the following:

```
"Object{assigned: Array[5], unassigned: Array[1]}"
```

Now I want to enumerate the key-value pairs of each property in both the 'assigned' array and the 'unassigned array'.

The configs object is structured in the following way:

Sorry fellas.  This is the structure of the configs objects:

```
var configs = {
"config1":
        {
        "assigned": [
            {
                "name": "Admin Usersss",
                "value": "admin-user"
            },
            {
                "name": "MPR User",
                "value": "mpr-user"
            },
            {
                "name": "SAMHSA User",
                "value": "samhsa-user"
            }
         ],
        "unassigned": [
            {
                "name": "States User",
                "value": "states-user"
            },
            {
                "name": "All States User",
                "value": "all-states-user"
            },
            {
                "name": "Substance Abuse User",
                "value": "substance-abuse-user"
            }
         ]
        },
"config2":
        {
        "assigned": [
            {
                "name": "Admin User",
                "value": "admin-user"
            },
            {
                "name": "MPR User",
                "value": "mpr-user"
            },
            {
                "name": "SAMHSA User",
                "value": "samhsa-user"
            },
            {
                "name": "States User",
                "value": "states-user"
            },
            {
                "name": "All States User",
                "value": "all-states-user"
            }
        ],
        "unassigned": [
            {
                "name": "Substance Abuse User",
                "value": "substance-abuse-user"
            }
        ]
    },
    "config3":
    {
        "assigned": [
            {
                "name": "Admin User",
                "value": "admin-user"
            }
        ],
        "unassigned": [
            {
                "name": "States User",
                "value": "states-user"
            },
            {
                "name": "All States User",
                "value": "all-states-user"
            },
            {
                "name": "Substance Abuse User",
                "value": "substance-abuse-user"
            },
            {
                "name": "MPR User",
                "value": "mpr-user"
            },
            {
                "name": "SAMHSA User",
                "value": "samhsa-user"
            }
            ]
        }
```

How do I do this?

Thanks, 
CM

Comment: Firstly note that you have two arrays, not key/value pairs. To achieve what you need you can use two loops, one over `configs.assigned` and another over `configs.unassigned`.

Comment: Arrays don't really have key-value pairs, just indices with content, but maybe `configs.assigned.concat(configs.unassigned).forEach( (index, value) => ...`

Comment: `In each array there are key value pairs I want to get at.` This cannot be the case, arrays cannot contain key/values. It would help if you could post the complete contents of the object instead of the console representation of it

Comment: Sorry.  Yeah each array contains objects that do contain key value pairs. And okay I know arrays have indexes with contents.

Comment: I added a working example for you which shows how to enumerate the keys of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the data structure you've posted you can use `Object.keys()` to enumerate the keys of the parent object and then loop over the `assigned` and `unassigned` properties within that. Try this:

```
Object.keys(configs).forEach(function(key) {
    var config = configs[key];

    config.assigned.forEach(function(assigned) {
        console.log('A: ' + assigned.name + ', ' + assigned.value);
    });

    config.unassigned.forEach(function(assigned) {
        console.log('U: ' + assigned.name + ', ' + assigned.value);
    });
})
```

```js
var configs = {
  "config1": {
    "assigned": [{
      "name": "Admin Usersss",
      "value": "admin-user"
    }, {
      "name": "MPR User",
      "value": "mpr-user"
    }, {
      "name": "SAMHSA User",
      "value": "samhsa-user"
    }],
    "unassigned": [{
      "name": "States User",
      "value": "states-user"
    }, {
      "name": "All States User",
      "value": "all-states-user"
    }, {
      "name": "Substance Abuse User",
      "value": "substance-abuse-user"
    }]
  },
  "config2": {
    "assigned": [{
      "name": "Admin User",
      "value": "admin-user"
    }, {
      "name": "MPR User",
      "value": "mpr-user"
    }, {
      "name": "SAMHSA User",
      "value": "samhsa-user"
    }, {
      "name": "States User",
      "value": "states-user"
    }, {
      "name": "All States User",
      "value": "all-states-user"
    }],
    "unassigned": [{
      "name": "Substance Abuse User",
      "value": "substance-abuse-user"
    }]
  },
  "config3": {
    "assigned": [{
      "name": "Admin User",
      "value": "admin-user"
    }],
    "unassigned": [{
      "name": "States User",
      "value": "states-user"
    }, {
      "name": "All States User",
      "value": "all-states-user"
    }, {
      "name": "Substance Abuse User",
      "value": "substance-abuse-user"
    }, {
      "name": "MPR User",
      "value": "mpr-user"
    }, {
      "name": "SAMHSA User",
      "value": "samhsa-user"
    }]
  }
}

Object.keys(configs).forEach(function(key) {
  var config = configs[key];
  config.assigned.forEach(function(assigned) {
    console.log(key + ' A: ' + assigned.name + ', ' + assigned.value);
  });
  config.unassigned.forEach(function(assigned) {
    console.log(key + ' U: ' + assigned.name + ', ' + assigned.value);
  });
})
```

Also note that (as pointed out by @adeneo in the comments on your question) if you're performing the same logic on both `assigned` and `unassigned` items then you can concatenate them together and iterate them once.

The above method would be required if the logic is different between properties.

Comment: Now how do take the name and value of each of the assigned and unassigned, and populate a select element with options containing the results something like: 

    $('#shutle-dst').html('<option value="value">"name"</option>');

Comment: That's an entirely separate goal which you should start a new question for. Although a similar question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery

Comment: This is definitely a tough programming technique isn't it. Newbie or otherwise right...

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
if(configs.assigned != undefined && configs.assigned != null && configs.assigned.length > 0) {
         // LOOP
}

if(configs.unassigned != undefined && configs.unassigned != null && configs.unassigned.length > 0) {
     // LOOP
}
```

Check here [Javascript unassigned var?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811001/javascript-unassigned-var)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the objects keys, then that objects keys, then those keys arrays:

```
for (var config in configs) {
    for (var configType in configs[config]) {
        for (var i = 0; i < configs[config][configType].length; i++) {
            var props = configs[config][configType][i];
            console.log(props);
        }
    }
}
```