# JavaScript function in object with parameter

Tags: javascript, object

I am using objects in JavaScript and try to call a function in a object with a parameter like:

```
obj.func(parameter);
```

The function is yet simple and just log the parameter in the console, or should do it.

```
func: function (txt) {
    console.log(txt);
}
```

The console just returns

> undefined

which means, as far i know, there is no parameter given.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: That would mean that the value of `parameter` is `undefined`.

Comment: Where is `parameter` set? If you never set the value, you're passing `undefined` into the function.

Comment: We need more information. Where is parameter coming from how is it set?

Comment: And what is the value of `parameter`?

Comment: Please post the section where you call the function. You're either passing `undefined` or not passing any parameters

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/r0sx3hee/). *"which means, as far i know, there is no parameter given"* Not necessarily, it can also mean it was given, and has the value `undefined`.

Comment: This was just an example my code is much longer, its all set. I thought i did something wrong, and i really did: i ended with a "," character at the end of the object. Removed it and it worked... lol.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you either have not defined your object correctly or the parameter is undefined. Check the following code:

```js
// Say you defined obj as follows:
var obj = {
  name: 'some name',
  data: 'some data',
  func: function (txt) {
    console.log(txt);
  }
}
// Say you define paramater as follows:
var parameter = 'I am a parameter!';
// And finally you call the function like so:
obj.func(parameter);
// Or maybe like so:
obj.func('I am another parameter!');
```

You have to instantiate your complex object properly **and** define a value for your `parameter` to show up in the console before calling your function. By default the `parameter`'s value is `undefined`, thus it shows that in the console.

Comment: @Deep I would ask the same. Given what the OP asked, this is the kind of solution that one can suggest for the problem...

Comment: Yes,i believe it should be mandatory to give some explanation for down voting an answer. it will help the person to understand at least what wrong he did, if he did any.

Comment: I hope the downvoter can explain themselves so I can see if I have made any mistake or my answer was inappropriate.

Comment: I asked myself the same, but dont worry i havent done this. I cant even vote :)

Comment: @prxy1 I can tell from your reputation that you are a new member. Anyways if you found any of the answers useful, upvote and/or approve them when you get the priveleges! Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0):

It will be actually a [Reference Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) if you have not declared the `parameter`

Since it is `undefined` most likely it is uninitialized
and left only with `var parameter;`

Initialized with some value like

```
var parameter ="abc";
```

In js [Default Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560362/when-declaring-a-variable-in-javascript-is-the-default-value-null) of a variable is `undefined`

Check this [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/yeo9u779/)